# getApplicationContext() on null object, React Native Android module

Tags: java, react-native, module, sdk

Currently creating a native android module for my react native application using a java SDK. I try to initiate the SDK which needs a context as a parameter. Here is the code:

```
public class LcrSdkModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    Context context;


    LcrSdkModule(ReactApplicationContext ReactContext) {
        super(ReactContext);
        this.context = ReactContext.getApplicationContext(); // This is where you get the context
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "LcrSdkModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public int printSomething(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    private LcrSdk lcrSdk = new LcrSdk(this.context);
}
```

The "private LcrSdk lcrSdk = new LcrSdk(this.context);" is where the code is failing if I'm not mistaken. Here is the error I'm receiving on the react native metro side:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
```

Any advice here? Just seems like ReactContext is null.

Comment: Well presumably the `ReactContext` parameter (which would be *much* less confusing if you used the conventional name of `reactContext`) is null. Without knowing what's calling the `LcrSdkModule` constructor, it's hard to say anything more.

Comment: I’m just trying to initiate the LrSdk in JavaScript using the native modules library from react native

Comment: Hmm... in that case it's basically "Why is the React native modules library passing in a null context" :(